# Mocking an ArrayList using PwerMock

Tags: junit, powermock

i am trying to mock an arraylist as follows using Powermock

### MockDao Class

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsDao.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(UtilityFunctions.class);
    DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsExport dailyExceptionsExport = Mockito.mock(DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsExport.class);
    List<DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsGridDto> resultList = getDailyExceptions(inputDto);
    try{
        PowerMockito.whenNew(DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsExport.class).withArguments(Mockito.any(DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsInputDto.class)).thenReturn(dailyExceptionsExport);
        Mockito.when(DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsDao.getDailyReceiptsAndExceptions(Mockito.any(DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsInputDto.class))).thenReturn(resultList);
        Mockito.when(UtilityFunctions.processReportSchedule(scheduleId, jobId,dailyExceptionsExport,(List<DailyReceiptsAndExceptionResultDTO>)Mockito.any(), null, null)).thenReturn(true);
}catch(Exception e){
    }
```

I need to write tests for the following class.

```
    public static Response getOutboundAvgCubeAndWeightUtilization(
        @QueryParam("dc") String dc,
        @QueryParam("asn") String asn,
        @QueryParam("sortBy") String sort,
        @QueryParam("isExport") boolean isExport,
        @QueryParam("fileType") String fileType,
        @QueryParam("scheduleId") BigDecimal scheduleId,
        @QueryParam("jobId") BigDecimal jobId)  {

    ResponseDTO responseDto = new ResponseDTO();

    DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsInputDto inputDto = new DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsInputDto ();
    inputDto.setAsn(asn);
    inputDto.setDc(dc);
    inputDto.setSortBy(sort);
    inputDto.setFileType(fileType);
    inputDto.setExport(isExport);
    String filePath = "";
    try {
        DailyReceiptsAndExceptionResultDTO resultDto = DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsBusinessManager.getInstance().manageDailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetails(inputDto);
        List<DailyReceiptsAndExceptionResultDTO> resultsList = new ArrayList<DailyReceiptsAndExceptionResultDTO>();
        resultsList.add(resultDto);
        if(scheduleId != null) {
            boolean responseStatus = UtilityFunctions.processReportSchedule(scheduleId, jobId, new DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsExport(inputDto), resultsList, null,null);

            responseDto.setResult(Boolean.toString(responseStatus));

            return CommonUtil.convertResponseToJson(responseDto);
        } 
   }
```

My tests class is as follows.

```
   @Test
public void testGetOutboundAvgCubeAndWeightUtilization_4()
    throws Exception {
    String dc = "5854";
    String asn = "*";
    String sort = "SKU";
    boolean isExport = false;
    String fileType = "";
    BigDecimal scheduleId = new BigDecimal(100);
    BigDecimal jobId = new BigDecimal(100);
    DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsInputDto inputDto = new DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsInputDto ();
    inputDto.setAsn(asn);
    inputDto.setDc(dc);
    inputDto.setSortBy(sort);
    inputDto.setFileType(fileType);
    inputDto.setExport(isExport);
    DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsMockDAO.mockgetDailyExceptions(inputDto, scheduleId, jobId);
    Response result = DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsDetailsService.getOutboundAvgCubeAndWeightUtilization(dc, asn, sort, isExport, fileType, scheduleId, jobId);
    String output = result.getEntity().toString();      
    assertEquals(true,output.contains("\"result\": \"true\""));
}
```

when iam running the test case, it was throwing error because, i think the mocking of the list is not correct.

Can anybody tell how to run this test scenario ....

Comment: Please could you add the error's stacktrace.

Comment: @StefanBirkner
 I am getting the following error trace, java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<true> but was:<false> at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88) at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743) at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118) at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)

Comment: The title seems a bit misleading as I can't find anywhere a definition of a mocked list. Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve because I somehow suspect that you might be trying to mock the following invocation: `UtilityFunctions.processReportSchedule(scheduleId, jobId, new DailyReceiptsAndExceptionsExport(inputDto), resultsList, null,null);`

Answer (score 3):

Your mocks appear to be fine.

JUnit is failing the test because the line

```
assertEquals(true,output.contains("\"result\": \"true\""));
```

is failing: this means that your String `output` does not contain the text `"result": "true"`

Perhaps one way for you to figure out what is wrong is to either print out the value of output prior to the `assertEquals()` call or use a debugger to see what the value of output is.

As a side note, `assertEquals(true, <condition>)` is very verbose, you can use `assertTrue(<condition>)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment the test is simply failing. (AssertionErrors are JUnit's way of saying that your test failed.)

You could get a better error message if you use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/). Therefore you have to change the last two lines of your code:

```
assertThat(result.getEntity(), hasToString(containsString("\"result\": \"true\"")));
```

Add some static imports for `org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat` and `org.hamcrest.Matchers.*`.

The new error message may help you finding the error.